# difference between I EXPECTED and I HAD EXPECTED

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "I expected" and "I had expected"?

Answer (score -1):

Use "had" for something that happened prior to something else in the past. For example: "John expected Alice to accept his proposal, but he had expected Loretta to marry him last year too and that never worked out."

[Duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326512/simple-past-tense-vs-perfect-past-tense)